# Bibliography as appendix causes problems for further appendixes

Tags: appendices

The document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{foo}
\appendix
\section{More Details}
\end{document}
```

The output:

```
[...]
11pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the 
same identifier (name{section.A}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

The document looks like (appendix numbers are duplicate):

```
A. References
...
A. More Details
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the second `\appendix`, and you also had a missing `}` on your example. (Maybe missed on copy/paste?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{References}} % <- was missing
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{foo}
%\appendix  <- don't need this
\section{More Details}
\end{document}
```

The `\appendix` instruction resets the numbering of chapters and makes them use letters (A, B, ...) rather than numbers (1, 2, ...). So you only need to use it once before all of your appendices.